# Установка библиотеки Kingfisher

Tags: xcode, swift

Пытаюсь установить библиотеку Kingfisher. После всех проделанных действий, выдает ошибку:

> Showing Recent Issues
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Может кто сталкивался?

**При загрузке alamofire**

```
 ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/vladislavbublik/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Моя_библиотека_PS4-gwvbjxjqgnsaxkgcvrdxdrsiybxk/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Alamofire'
ld: framework not found Alamofire
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Через pod ставили?

Comment: через CocoaPods и Carthage

Comment: Проект чистили?

Comment: нет, установил, запустил, ошибка
какие действия нужно выполнить?

Comment: Product -> Clean

Comment: почистил, проблема осталась

Comment: Вы пробывали через pod или carthage? Или пробывали и то и другое?

Comment: и то и другое пробовал и все вместе и как только не пробовал )

Comment: Ну если даже так, рекомендую вам снести и там и там и добавить только в pod. Дело в том, что у вас могли возникнуть конфликты.

Comment: да вот ставлю только pod сейчас, все равно ошибка, попробовал alamofire, все равно ошибка, запускаю чистый проект без библиотек - работает, в чем проблема, не понимаю

Comment: вот что пишет если ставлю pod alamofire, в посте обновил

Comment: кажется решил проблему) удалил из framework папку Pods

Comment: только из за этого у меня пропала вся анимация)))